# What's a good way to collect logs from Amazon EC2 instances?

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My app is hosted on an Amazon EC2 cluster. Each instance writes events to log files. I need to collect (and data mine) over these logs at the end of each day. What's a recommended way to collect these logs in a central location? I have thought of several options, not sure which way to go:

1. scp them to an instance using a cron job
2. Log all events over TCP/IP to an instance

Answer (score 23):

We use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) on each host (deployed via Puppet) to gather and ship log events to a message queue (RabbitMQ, but could be Redis) on a central host. Another Logstash instance retrieves the events, processes them and stuffs the result into [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). A [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) web interface is used to search through this database.

It's very capable, scales easily and is very flexible. Logstash has tons of filters to process events from various inputs, and can output to lots of services, ElasticSearch being one of them. We currently ship about 1,2 million log events per day from our EC2 instances, on light hardware. The latency for a log event from event to searchable is about 1 second in our setup.

Here's some documentation on this kind of setup: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html, and a demo of the Kibana search interface with some live data.

Comment: To add on to this, if you find logstash's performance on your host to be too demanding you may want to look into https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder .  It's written in golang and has much less overhead than the entire logstash project, but has enough inputs to do the job of getting the logs off of your host and into your logging system (where you can then mangle them with logstash's various input plugins).

Comment: I would recommend shipping the logs to S3 and then tailing the log from s3 using logstash+elasticsearch. (Use checksum to generate elasticsearch ID to dedup log entries caused by logstash reprocessing reuploaded files). This way you don't have to worry about losing your Elasticsearch cluster and makes repositioning your ES cluster a lot easier and cleaner. It also opens you up to a lot more heavier analytics tools such as EMR and Redshift.

Comment: These days, Logstash-forwarder has been replaced by various Beats (https://www.elastic.co/products/beats). Filebeat for logfiles, Metricbeat for metrics, Packetbeat for network traffic logging, etc. They're very lightweight.
Also, Logstash 5.4 has a feature called Persistent Queue that reduces the need for a separate message queue, making deployment easier.

Answer (score 10):

This question is old now (December 2014) but still ranks highly during a Google search on this topic.

Amazon now provides a way to do some of this through CloudWatch. It has the capability to pattern-match the log message and trigger alarms based on things happening in the application. Depending on the nature of the data-mining that needs to be done, it may be possible to use their API to fetch the desired, aggregate events. See http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/

Answer (score 7):

I've been using Loggly and it seems to do the trick

http://loggly.com/

It allows me to send all my logs through tcp to their service and have a central place to monitor all my log files,

It also allows me to archive my log files to S3 which is nice too

Comment: "It also allows me to archive my log files to S3 which is nice too", does this mean that loggly is your first destination point?, logfiles are sent there and then you make loggly send compressed archives to S3? 
I'm trying to get this setup where I have a centralized monitoring for all my logfiles but I can still keep the archived .gz files on s3

Answer (score 6):

I've not tried it for this purpose, but Amazon appear to recommend using SimpleDB:

http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/usecases_logging/

Here's a package that you might find useful - it says you can use it to capture stdout/stderr into SimpleDB:

http://code.google.com/p/simpledb-appender/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the free version of [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) - it will handle the remote log file collection and also give you some really nice search and analysis tools.

Answer (score 3):

Use syslog-ng, a popular tool that transfers log messages over TCP, optionally encrypted.

http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't implemented it yet, but I came across Facebook Scribe, and it seems like a good idea.  https://github.com/facebookarchive/scribe

Until I get that going I've been doing just what you mention for #1 - I have a cron job which uses sftp to pull the files.  I chose this because even if I did #2, I've had instances where the ec2 machine crashes and I ended up having to pull the logfiles off anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work at Sumo:

Sumo Logic Free is a relatively easy option as well:

https://www.sumologic.com/pricing/